# C# get subquery records of custom object

Tags: soql, c#, enterprise-wsdl, subquery

Let's say I have a query like this:

```
Select Name,Color, (select Id,Amount from Custom_2__r) from Custom_1__c Where Custom_1__c.Id='111'
```

In C# I see that 'Custom_1__c[0].Custom_2__r' is of type QueryResult (which make sense as it is a subquery).

It also has 'Custom_1__c[0].Custom_2__r.records' which is of type sObject[]

I've tried:

```
foreach(Custom_2__c c2 in Custom_1__c[0].Custom_2__r.records)
{
}
```

and got the error 'Unable to cast object of type sObject to type Custom_2__c'

Then I tried the QueryResult path with doing this:

```
QueryResult qr = Custom_1__c[0].Custom_2__r;
for (int i = 0; i < qr.records.Length; i++)
{
    Custom_2__c c2 = (Custom_2__c)qr.records[i];
    if (c2.Id != null)
    {
         
    }

}
```

with the same error at the type casting line.

How do I go about getting those records in the subquery?

thanks!

Comment: What API are you using in C#? Are you going directly to the Partner or Enterprise API? Or are you using a library?

Comment: Enterprise API.

Answer (score 0):

The following works from me for the child relationship from the standard Account sObject to Contact.

```
EnterpriseApi.SessionHeader sessionHeader = new EnterpriseApi.SessionHeader();
sessionHeader.sessionId = "00D300000000001!AQ0AQBURgNotARealSessionIdu02H2";

string serverUrl = "https://na87.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/49/00D300000000001"; // /c/ for Enterprise WSDL

string endpointConfigurationName = "Soap"; // From the .config file
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(serverUrl);

string queryString = "Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Contacts) from Account";

EnterpriseApi.SoapClient enterpriseApi = new EnterpriseApi.SoapClient(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress);
EnterpriseApi.QueryResult result = null;
enterpriseApi.query(sessionHeader, null, null, null, queryString, out result);

foreach(EnterpriseWsdlTest.EnterpriseApi.Account account in result.records)
{
    if(account.Contacts != null && account.Contacts.size > 0)
    {
        foreach(EnterpriseWsdlTest.EnterpriseApi.Contact contact in account.Contacts.records)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Contact : " + contact.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

This works equally well for a Master-Detail relationship between a parent custom SObject and a child custom SObject.

```
// Session ID / URL code is the same.

string queryString = "Select Id, (Select Id from ChildCustomObjectValues__r) from ParentCustomObject__c limit 10";

EnterpriseApi.SoapClient enterpriseApi = new EnterpriseApi.SoapClient(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress);
EnterpriseApi.QueryResult result = null;
enterpriseApi.query(sessionHeader, null, null, null, queryString, out result);

foreach(EnterpriseWsdlTest.EnterpriseApi.ParentCustomObject__c parentCustomObject in result.records)
{
    if(parentCustomObject.ChildCustomObjectValues__r != null && parentCustomObject.ChildCustomObjectValues__r.size > 0)
    {
        foreach(EnterpriseWsdlTest.EnterpriseApi.ChildCustomObjectValue__c childCustomObject in parentCustomObject.ChildCustomObjectValues__r.records)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Child : " + childCustomObject.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to cast the SObject that came out of the records directly into the child sObject type.